# PDF Markers visible on Document

Tags: pdf, adobe

Is there a way to add a marker on to a PDF that is not contained within the Bookmark panel and visible on the PDF itself. So that our client can just click on the marker to bring him to a specific point in the document. These will be changes that are revisions and not necessarily to do with the structure of the document. I feel like I have seen this in the past but unsure how to go about creating it. Any advisement you may have to offer is greatly appreciated.

I am running AA XI Pro.

Thank you,

Comment: You mean a link *on* the page or something floating over the document that is persistent across pages?

Comment: Yes exactly like that! I know I have seen it, just wondering how I can make it happen using Adobe XI Pro

Comment: Exactly like which? I presented two possible options.

Comment: My apologies, something floating over the document that is persistent across all pages like a blue flag that hovers over the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can create floating toolbar using the code below as an example. **cExec** is the JavaScript expression string to evaluate when the button is clicked. **oIcon**, which is optional, is a document level icon that you would have previously added to the document using...

```
this.addIcon("iconName", "iconPath");
```

You can just run the code to add the icon from the console since you only need to do it once.

Add the code below to a Document JavaScript so that it loads every time the document is opened.

```
app.addToolButton({
  cName: "goToPage",
  oIcon: util.iconStreamFromIcon(this.getIcon("LinkIcon")), // Needs to already be a document level Icon object in the document
  cExec: "this.pageNum=41",
  cTooltext: "Got To Page 42",
  cEnable: true,
});
```

You can add as many buttons as you like but each **cName** needs to be unique. Also, This will only work in the desktop versions of the Adobe viewers.

You can find a working example of the code above [here](http://practicalpdf.com/downloads/FloatingToolbar.pdf)